# Recursive palindrome returns statement over and over

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop, return, palindrome

I can't figure out why, but my program just keeps returning the one statement over and over until I close the application. It works without the while loop, but I need to be able to have them keep entering a word or phrase until they choose to quit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RecursivePalindrome{

    public static boolean recursivePalindromeTester(String str1){
        if(str1.length() == 0 || str1.length() == 1){
            return true; 
        }
        if(str1.charAt(0) == str1.charAt(str1.length()-1)){
            return recursivePalindromeTester(str1.substring(1, str1.length()-1));
        }
        return false;  
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word, phrase, or string of words.(q to quit)");
        String str1 = in.nextLine();
        str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
        while (str1 != "q"){
            if (recursivePalindromeTester(str1)){
                System.out.println(str1 + " is a palindrome");
            } else{
                System.out.println(str1 + " is not palindrome");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do simpler: compare your input to it's reversed version using StringBuilder (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 4):

Problem is, your `str1` is not getting updated inside the `while` loop, so the while loop becomes an `infinite-loop`.

So you need to read `str1` inside the while loop too.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word, phrase, or string of words.(q to quit)");
    String str1 = in.nextLine();
    str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    while (!str1.equals("q")){
        if (recursivePalindromeTester(str1)){
            System.out.println(str1 + " is a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println(str1 + " is not palindrome");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the next string.(q to quit)");
        str1 = in.nextLine(); // <--- Here you must update str1.
        str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare your exiting char the right way, otherwise won't terminate either.

Your input has to match it's reversed version to be a palindrome. Therefore you could simply use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) with its `reverse`-method.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
    return input.equals(builder.reverse().toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word, phrase, or string of words.(q to quit)");
    String str1 = in.nextLine();
    str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    while (!str1.equals("q")) {
        System.out.println(str1 + (isPalindrome(str1) ? " is a palindrome" : " is not palindrome"));
        System.out.println("Enter the next string.(q to quit)");
        str1 = in.nextLine();
        str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you needed to put str1 = in.nextLine() in the while loop. Otherwise it will keep the first value and keep firing the loop. Hope this helps.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class RecursivePalindrome{

     public static boolean recursivePalindromeTester(String str1){
         if(str1.length() == 0 || str1.length() == 1){
             return true; 
         }
         if(str1.charAt(0) == str1.charAt(str1.length()-1)){
             return recursivePalindromeTester(str1.substring(1, str1.length()-1));
         }
         return false;
     }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word, phrase, or string of words.(q to quit)");
        String str1 = "";
        while (str1 != "q"){
            str1 = in.nextLine();
            str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
            if(str1.equals("q")){break;}
            if (recursivePalindromeTester(str1)){
                System.out.println(str1 + " is a palindrome");
            }else{
                System.out.println(str1 + " is not palindrome");
            }
        }
    }
}
```